# Calling same method on different object - Recursion?

Tags: object-oriented, recursion

I have an object that contains a reference to another object of the same type.  Example in PHP:

```
class A {
    protected $child;
    public function __construct(A $child = null) {
        $this->child = $child;
    }

    public function go() {
        if($this->child) {
            $this->child->go();
        }
    }
}

$a = new A(new A());
$a->go();
```

Is the `go` method considered a recursive method?  I can see it both ways myself, and I'm not sure if there is a 'correct' answer or not, but I assume that there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29), since the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) needs to grow. A new call frame has to be pushed (to the *same* function).

If the `go` method called another `foo` method (even on an unrelated class) which itself calls again `go` on the same class, you would have a [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) ...

Another way to look at that is noticing that method invocation is just a [dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table) phase (computing which function should really be called depending upon the receiver), followed by a function call (whose first argument is the reciever).

However, read about [tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (or *tail recursion*). It enables to replace the current call frame with the newly called one (without growing the call stack).

So good compilers implement a *tail call* as a "jump with arguments"; read also about [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style)

Comment: Isn't a new call frame pushed for every function call, recursive or not?  I'm not disagreeing, just wondering how the fact that the call stack growing alone makes a method 'recursive'. I guess you could make the argument that, regardless what object I'm in, the return address coming off the call stack in both instances is the same

Comment: Agreed. I improved my answer.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, a function doesn't need to call itself *directly* to be considered recursive; see [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) (e.g. `f` calls `g` and `g` calls `f`).

Answer (score 2):

The instance on which the method is invoked (the *receiver* of the *message*, in Smalltalk terms) is typically treated as an implicit, zeroth parameter to the method.

So a method like

`public function go()`

that takes no arguments can be thought of as actually taking one argument, named `$this`, of type `A`:

`public function go(A $this)`

And a call to that method, dispatched on some particular instance of `A`, could then be thought of, not as being written

`$this->child->go()`

but rather written like this:

`go($this->child)`

When looked at in these terms, it clearly becomes a recursive call. (The Cfront C++ compiler, in the very early days of C++, translated C++ into C code like this, which was then compiled with a C compiler.)